# Last row in CSS Grid where cells have a footer and are stretched to same height drawing strangely

Tags: html, css, css-grid, css-tables

I have a code pen at https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/wveJqXd

What I am looking to achieve is the following:

1. I have an arbitrary number of cells. This example only uses 10, but it could be more or less than 10
2. Each cell has a footer which needs to be aligned to the bottom of cell so that they are aligned across cells in the same row
3. The height of a cell can vary, but the height needs to be stretched so every cell in the same row has the same height to support #2

This almost works perfectly using Safari ( Version 14.1.2 (15611.3.10.1.5, 15611) ), but the last cell in the last row is wider than it should be.

[image: Safari]

The behavior is worse in Chrome ( Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (x86_64) ). The rows are drawn higher than they should be. The last cell in the last row is to wide.

[image: Chrome]

Is this due to a lack of complete browser support?

If this is due to not specifying my css correctly, what do I need to do?

```css
.example1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  align-items: stretch;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.contentdiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.foot {
  display: table-row;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <div class="contentdiv">1<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">2
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">3
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">4
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">5a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">6
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">7a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">8
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">9
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">10a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing. Try adding this to your CSS -> `* {box-sizing: border-box}`

Comment: `display:table` is not a good idea here (`table-layout:fixed`  would be required for the `width`) and `height : 1px` (expanded cause of the table-layout display)  is also not a good idea, while `flex` or `grid` will do this without sides effects minus the `box-sizing:border-box` missing to mind `height:100%` and `padding`/ `border`.To set that element at the bottom, flex or grid should be the way to IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the setting the display to `table` for the `contentdiv` - and setting it's width and height to `100%`.

Basically what is happening - if you view your elements in the web inspector - you'll see that all of your elements are wider than `300px` because of the padding `1rem`, so they are actually overlapping already, you just can't visually see it until the last row.

You can avoid this setting, `* { box-sizing: border-box }` and the display to `flex` instead, and using the `justify-content` property to keep the `foot` aligned on all rows:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  align-items: stretch;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.contentdiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Avoid the borders stacking */
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <div class="contentdiv">1<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">2
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">3
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">4
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">5a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">6
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">7a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">8
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">9
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">10a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my comment,

> `display:table` is not a good idea here (`table-layout:fixed`  would be required for the `width`) and `height : 1px` (expanded cause of the table-layout display)  is also not a good idea, while `flex` or `grid` will do this without sides effects minus the `box-sizing:border-box` missing to mind `height:100%` and `padding`/ `border`.To set that element at the bottom, flex or grid should be the way to IMHO

here is an example with grid instead table for display ;)

```css
.example1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  align-items: stretch;
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.contentdiv {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
}

.foot {
  margin-top:auto;/* push it all the way down */
}
```

```html
<div class="example1">
  <div class="contentdiv">1<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">2
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">3
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">4
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">5a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">6
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">7a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">8
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">9
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">10a<br/>a<br/>a<br/>
    <div class="foot">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not clear about the requirement you have put in ,if you are expecting this ()
Also you can better play around with flex property which is easier
[grid image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJHEG.png)
if so I just changed the height in class contentdiv to inherit.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.